iOS AWS SDK + Amplify - unable to access SecretsManager values
I am trying to access secrets stored in AWSSecretManager with an authenticated session using Amplify.
Got the following 2 functions :
public static func getAWSCredentials() async throws -> AWSCredentials {
        let authSession = try await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession()

        guard let awsCredentialsProvider = authSession as? AuthAWSCredentialsProvider else {
            throw NSError(domain: "", code: -1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Auth session does not conform to AuthAWSCredentialsProvider"])
        }

        let awsCredentialsValue = try awsCredentialsProvider.getAWSCredentials().get()
        return awsCredentialsValue
    }

    public static func getSecretValue() async -> String? {
        
            do {
                let credentials = try await getAWSCredentials()
                               
                let manager = try AWSSecretsManager.SecretsManagerClient(region: "eu-central-1")
                
                let getSecretValueInput = GetSecretValueInput(secretId: "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-central-1:#######:######:#####/#####/#########")
                let secretValueOutput = try await manager.getSecretValue(input: getSecretValueInput)
                return secretValueOutput.secretString
            }
            catch let error {
                print("Unexpected error: \(error)")
                return nil
            }
    }

basically calling getSecretValue() results in unauthenticated error and it seems somehow AWSCredentials  instance (which is valid) has to be passed to the SecretsManagerClient but have no success as any kind of possible ways are not available or deprecated.
Does anyone knows how that could be done ? Is this approach right or is there another way to do it ?
Tried to go through the documentation and guessing the possible ways to supply the Amplify.Auth credentials to the AWSSecretManagerClient with no success.
